# Airflow - 2 alerts are send on_failure

Tags: email, airflow

I have a strange bug on Airflow 1.10.
I wanted to try to send email and a notification on Microsoft Teams.
I made a small dumb DAG to try it out.
Everything is working well but I got 2 notifications on a row. 2 Emails and 2 Messages on Teams.

I used this for Teams : https://github.com/mendhak/Airflow-MS-Teams-Operator

Here the Dags :

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from operators.ms_teams_webhook_operator import MSTeamsWebhookOperator
from airflow.utils.email import send_email_smtp

default_args = {
    "owner": "me",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2020, 6, 15),
    'email_on_failure': False
}


def on_failure(context):
    dag_id = context['dag_run'].dag_id

    task_id = context['task_instance'].task_id
    # context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key=dag_id, value=True)

    logs_url = f"https://myairflow/admin/airflow/log?dag_id={dag_id}&task_id={task_id}&execution_date={context['ts']}"

    teams_notification = MSTeamsWebhookOperator(
        task_id="msteams_notify_failure",
        trigger_rule="all_done",
        message=f"{dag_id} has failed on task: {task_id}",
        button_text="View log",
        button_url=logs_url,
        theme_color="FF0000",
        http_conn_id='msteams-python-webhook')
    teams_notification.execute(context)

    title = f"Titre {dag_id} - {task_id}"
    body = title

    send_email_smtp("gil.felot@lisea.fr", title, body)


def print_fail():
    print("Hello !")
    exit(1)


with DAG(
        "test_email2",  # ICI
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None
) as dag:
    preprocessing_started = DummyOperator(
        task_id="go_email_go"
    )

    python_fail = PythonOperator(
        task_id="pyhton_def",
        python_callable=print_fail,
        on_failure_callback=on_failure,
        email_on_failure=False
    )

preprocessing_started >> python_fail
```

EDIT :

Using the Hook instead. Now nothing is trigerred

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.email import send_email_smtp
from hooks.ms_teams_webhook_hook import MSTeamsWebhookHook


def on_failure(context):
    dag_id = context['dag_run'].dag_id

    task_id = context['task_instance'].task_id
    # context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key=dag_id, value=True)

    logs_url = f"https://myairflow/admin/airflow/log?dag_id={dag_id}&task_id={task_id}&execution_date={context['ts']}"

    teams_notification_hook = MSTeamsWebhookHook(
        http_conn_id='msteams-python-webhook',
        message=f"Le DAG {dag_id} a échoué sur la tâche : {task_id}",
        subtitle="Voir les logs ?",
        button_text="Logs",
        button_url=logs_url,
        theme_color="FF0000"
    )
    teams_notification_hook.execute()

    title = f"Titre {dag_id} - {task_id}"
    body = title

    send_email_smtp("my@email.fr", title, body)


def on_success(context):
    print("OK callback")
    dag_id = context['dag_run'].dag_id

    for i in context.items():
        print(i)

    teams_notification_hook = MSTeamsWebhookHook(
        http_conn_id='msteams-python-webhook',
        message=f"Le DAG {dag_id} s'est terminé avec succès",
        theme_color="00EE00"
    )
    teams_notification_hook.execute(context)

    title = f"Titre {dag_id} - Success"
    body = title

    send_email_smtp("my@email.fr", title, body)


default_args = {
    "owner": "lisea-mesea",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2020, 6, 15),
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "on_failure_callback": on_success
    # "on_failure_callback": on_failure
}


def print_fail():
    print("Hello !")
    exit(1)


with DAG(
        "test_email2",  # ICI
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None
) as dag:
    preprocessing_started = DummyOperator(
        task_id="go_email_go"
    )

    python_fail = PythonOperator(
        task_id="pyhton_def",
        python_callable=print_fail,
        # on_failure_callback=on_failure,
        email_on_failure=False
    )

preprocessing_started >> python_fail
```

Comment: Was the `pyhton_def` task retried after it failed by airflow?

Comment: Nope, as you can see in the DAG... no retry included

Comment: It wasn't clear if a  task retry policy is configured in the Airflow environment, hence my asking that.

Comment: Where can I see that ? I have nothing fancy in my installation I guess.

Comment: You can quickly find that by navigating to the Admin > Configuration view.

Comment: Any chance you're getting the same number of emails/notifications as the number of tasks present? Can you try adding 1 more task and see if you get 3 emails?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend strongly to use the [MSTeamsWebhookHook](https://github.com/mendhak/Airflow-MS-Teams-Operator/blob/master/ms_teams_webhook_hook.py#L24) in the `on_failure_callback` instead of the `MSTeamsWebhookOperator`.

Without going much into the weeds, the `BaseOperator` from which `MSTeamsWebhookOperator` inherits tries to rig it [to the current dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L419) when it's instantiated.

The [dag property setter](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L419) is can be seen to register the task instance on the dag.

This means that asides from manual execution of the operator taking place in the `on_failure_callback`, a task instance for `MSTeamsWebhookOperator` is scheduled.
The later is not intended as we only care is for the capability to send notifications provided in the Hook when a task fails.

This doesn't give an explanation for why emails are sent out twice as that doesn't appear to be using an Operator. That requires a separate investigation.

Comment: I get it and without knowing everything under the hood it was strange to follow the tutorial and use an Operator. So in this case how can I give the information to the hook about the message and everything ?

Comment: Not too differently from how you provide information to the Operator. The options to pass are in the [constructor signature](https://github.com/mendhak/Airflow-MS-Teams-Operator/blob/master/ms_teams_webhook_hook.py#L49). Also, remember to execute the Hook without no arguments.

Comment: I just edit my question for how I call the hook because nothing happen now.

Comment: [MSTeamsWebhookOperator.execute](https://github.com/mendhak/Airflow-MS-Teams-Operator/blob/master/ms_teams_webhook_hook.py#L120) doesn't accept any arguments. In your on_success function which you have set for the `on_failure_callback`, you have passed in context there.

Comment: My bad... just a typo. I still have 2 notifications but it's cleaner.